# In place initialization of POD

Tags: c++, c++03

I do not think "in place" is the right term, but I am lacking a better one.

I have a POD, let's say:

```
struct My {
    int a;
};
//and suppose a operator<< to stream is also defined
```

And I may use it right this:

```
My my = {3};
std::cout << my << std::endl;
```

I am wondering if I can do the same below but without using a helper func:

```
template <typename ANY>
My helper(ANY value) {
    My r = {value};
    return r;
}
std::cout << helper(3) << std::endl;
```

I am looking for the same thing that a constructor does, but since I have a POD I can not create a constructor.

Comment: Too bad you've specified [tag:c++03] - you could have done `My{3}` in [tag:c++11].

Comment: @sftrabbit Too bad msvc lack good support for C++11. I hate working with msvc.

Comment: Regarding "in place initialization", I think that you mean "[aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
struct My {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    float d;
};

void somefunc() {
   cout << (My){1, 2, 3, 4.5} << endl;
}
```

Comment: Now that's syntax I have never seen before. I thought that braced init list before C++11 could be only used in initializers.

Comment: g++ 4.7.2 complains about this syntax with the "`-pedantic`" flag enabled:  "`warning: ISO C++ forbids compound-literals [-pedantic]`"